# ZRANGESTORE prior Redis 6.2.0

Tags: redis, sortedset

Basically I would like to store the top 5 from a sorted set in different set.
In redis 6.2 I can do it with `ZRANGESTORE` with `REV` option.
What is the alternative in lower versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this does what I need:

```
eval "
redis.call('DEL','final') 
local set=redis.call('ZREVRANGE','out',0,4,'withscores') 
for i = 1, #set/2 do 
  set[2*i-1], set[2*i] = set[2*i], set[2*i-1] 
end 
return redis.call('ZADD','final',unpack(set))
" 0
```